# Как подключить модуль node js, к html странице

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Есть два файла js и один html

Задача: Использовать функцию из файла sha256.js в файле login.js

Ошибка:

```
login.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at login.js:1:14
```

HTML

```
<script src="script/sha256.js"></script>
<script src="script/login.js"></script>
```

login.js

```
var sha256 = require('./sha256.js');


document.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {
    let login = document.getElementById("login").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("passwd").value;

    if (sha256(login) == "6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b" && sha256(password) == "6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b") {
        alert("Yes!")
    }
    else alert("Incorrect login or password!");
}
```

Мне нужно просто захешировать данные из формы html, который обрабатывает файл login.js и проверить с хешом в условии.

Я понимаю, что можно использовать библиотеки Browserify, Webpack и т.д., но может есть другой вариант? Или может есть какая-то более простая библиотека? Сервер будет работать на nodejs

Comment: Подключить "модуль node.JS" к HTML станице не получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все проверки авторизации делается на стороне сервера. На клиенте тебе нужно обработать на валидность введенных данных, потом отправить эти данные на сервере и ждать пока там произойдет проверка, и соответственно выводить результат тут.

Например:

```js
$("#login_form").submit((e)=>{
  e.preventDefault()
  
  //проверка валидности
  
  $.ajax({
    url:'хост апи/роут до метода',
    data:{
      login:$('input[name=login]').val(),
      password:$('input[name=password]').val()  
    },
    method:'POST',
    success:function(res){
      //обрабатываешь ответ
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <form id="login_form">
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="логин">
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="пароль">
    </form>
```